# Create Sharepoint Columns from Word doc form fields?

Tags: word-automation

We are converting multiple Lotus Notes documents to Word docs and then uploading the Word docs into SharePoint Libraries. Some of the Word documents have information stored in Form Fields. For Example : BuyerName & SellerName. These fields need to be used in SP for sorting, filtering etc.

We have tried creating columns on SharePoint with the same names (BuyerName & SellerName) but the information from the Word docs does not display in the corresonding Sharepoint columns once the docs are uploaded.

Any advice on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Moving forward, you can create a document content type that has a site column corresponding to each form field, then pull the SharePoint site columns into your Word template directly (instead of creating them in Word first). That way, the fields in the Word form will also show up as metadata on the document item. That doesn't address your question, however, since it goes the opposite direction. You'll probably need to get some kind of third-party solution to export the form values as metadata.